# Make image html file but in parts

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to make a game where the players see the first line of the image and they try to guess which animal is it, if no one guesses correct it adds the next line and so on until the image is clear (if someone guessed correctly they win).

I'm having a problem where obviously I can't "img src" the image because I want to update the html file in parts every time the users get raw input.
I've tried doing it with normal jpg image that opens but it says it's undisplayable unless I send the full image.

If anyone knows how to help I'll be thankful!

Leo.

Comment: You need to help us help you by providing more information in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried? What frameworks are you planning on using?

Comment: Well, the best thing I've gotten is printing the picture as html page and resizing it from small to big, but someone with good eyes can already reveal the animal in the second resize. I would like to print it in parts such as from the top of the picture to the bottom in "cuts"